# Trigger Hover on EventListener added by Ajax

Tags: jquery

I have a (jquery) problem:

Let's say I have a link (regular a tag) that triggers an ajax request.
That request also adds a new hover event listener to the mentioned link which shows a popup on hover.

The problem is that when a user keeps hovering the link, the hover listener obvously isn't triggered as the mouseenter event is not triggered. It works of course when moving the mouse away and over the link again. Is there a possibility to check wheter the user is still hovering the link and trigger the mouseenter event?

Cheers!

Comment: Maybe use [`mouseover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event) instead of hover/mouseenter?   With so few details, just a guess what will work in your scenario.

Comment: Instead of creating the event during the request, you should always add the listener. The listener should set a variable or add a class. Sending the request also adds some class or sets a variable. If both are set the popup is shown... obviously not easy to describe. Please post source code.

Comment: As I understand the issue:  OP is pointing at an element with a popup shown via mouseenter - that element is then replaced via an ajax call and the popup disappears.  Moving the mouse out and back then reshows the popup.  So it's not an event binding issue.  It's unclear how the popup is shown, so it could just be a case of re-showing the popup if the flag (as described in above comment) is set.